# A question about Rails' "to_xml()"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I'm using this code

```
@events = Event.all(:include => [:facility_infos, :activity_infos], :conditions => ['infos.language_id = ? AND activity_infos_events.language_id = ?', 1, 1], :order => :time)
respond_to do |format|
  format.xml  { render :xml => @events.to_xml( 
    :skip_types => true,
    :except => :created_at,
    :include => {
      :facility_infos => {:only => :title}, 
      :activity_infos => {:only => :title}
      }) 
      }
```

to obtain the following XML

```
<events>
  <event>
    <activity-id>23</activity-id>
    <everyday>false</everyday>
    <facility-id>10</facility-id>
    <home>true</home>
    <id>3</id>
    <time>2011-04-21T17:30:00Z</time>
    <updated-at>2011-04-21T17:31:23Z</updated-at>
    <facility-infos>
      <facility-info>
        <title>Campi da calcetto</title>
      </facility-info>
    </facility-infos>
    <activity-infos>
      <activity-info>
        <title>Torneo di calcetto</title>
      </activity-info>
    </activity-infos>
  </event>
</events>
```

I'd like to have it look like this:

```
<events>
  <event>
    <activity-id>23</activity-id>
    <everyday>false</everyday>
    <facility-id>10</facility-id>
    <home>true</home>
    <id>3</id>
    <time>2011-04-21T17:30:00Z</time>
    <updated-at>2011-04-21T17:31:23Z</updated-at>
    <facility>Campi da calcetto</facility>
    <activity>Torneo di calcetto</activity>
  </event>
</events>
```

Please can you tell me how to change my code to obtain that?

Thanks!!

**EDIT**

My relations in the Event model:

```
 belongs_to  :activity
  belongs_to  :facility
  has_many    :activity_infos, :through => :activity, :source => :infos, :class_name => "Info"
  has_many    :facility_infos, :through => :facility, :source => :infos, :class_name => "Info"

  def infos
    activity_infos + facility_infos
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edited.

Indeed, if your relationships are `has_many`, the following doesn't make sense:

```
<facility>Campi da calcetto</facility>
<activity>Torneo di calcetto</activity>
```

Because you'll have many `facility_infos` and `activity_infos` to display. With this remark in mind I suggest the following.

Override `to_xml` in your model as follows:

```
def to_xml  options={}
  super(options) do |xml|
    xml.facility_infos do
      facility_infos.each do |facility|
        xml.facility_info facility.title
      end
    end
    xml.activity_infos do
      activity_infos.each do |activity|
        xml.activity_info activity.title
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And simply retrieve what you expect this way:

```
@events.to_xml( 
  :skip_types => true,
  :except => :created_at,
  )
```

Comment: I have the same problem, but the two attributes I want to append on the resulting XML come from a belongs_to instead of a has_many. Cannot  make it work following this answer. Is there a difference?